# Missing columns: Salesforce SOQL Multiple Join Query between two child objects (Team Members and Payment)

Tags: salesforce, soql

I'm trying to do a 'Join" to calculate what a team member gets paid based on money we receive.

On my Opportunity, I have two related lists, both Master/Child
1) Team Member - with the people who worked on the opportunity and the commission they should receive. They get paid when we get paid.
2) Payments - with the payments we receive.

I need to run a join query to match every Payment we receive in a period to the related team members of the same opportunity.

This query seems to work

```
SELECT Amount__c, Method__c, Opportunity__c ,OwnerId, User__c, RoleCode__c,  Name FROM Sales_Team__c  where Opportunity__c IN (SELECT Opportunity__c  FROM Payment__c) LIMIT 10
```

However, I need to see the Payment_Amount on the Payment object so I added it to the second 'select'

```
SELECT Amount__c, Method__c, Opportunity__c ,OwnerId, User__c, RoleCode__c,  Name FROM Sales_Team__c  where Opportunity__c IN (SELECT Opportunity__c  FROM Payment__c) LIMIT 10
```

Now I get this error

> ```
> There has been an error in the SOQL query:
> MALFORMED_QUERY: 
> Opportunity__c IN (SELECT Opportunity__c, Payment_Amount__c  FROM Payment__c)
>                                        ^
> ERROR at Row:1:Column:148
> unexpected token: ,
> ```

How do I pull in additional columns from my Payments table?

Any and all help would really appreciated.
Ian

Answer (score 0):

When you are looking for Opportunity__c in where clause , why are you adding  Payment_Amount__c in the query.

```
SELECT Opportunity__c, Payment_Amount__c  FROM Payment__c
```

This should work fine unless there is a typo in your query

```
SELECT Amount__c, Method__c, Opportunity__c ,OwnerId, User__c, RoleCode__c,  Name FROM Sales_Team__c  where Opportunity__c IN (SELECT Opportunity__c  FROM Payment__c) LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
SELECT Amount__c, Method__c, Opportunity__c ,OwnerId, User__c, RoleCode__c,  Name,(SELECT Opportunity__c, Payment_Amount__c  FROM Payment__c) FROM Sales_Team__c  where Opportunity__c IN (SELECT Opportunity__c  FROM Payment__c) LIMIT 10
```